# SAP HANA cannot add parameter to webdispatcher.ini

Tags: hana

SAP HANA Documentation and other sources state that you are sopposed to edit the webdispatcher.ini via the SAP HANA Studio -> Configuration -> webdispatcher.ini

Unfortunately I cannot add a parameter neither via the GUI (Context Menu "Add Parameter..." missing) nor via SQL commands (0 rows affected).

How to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

The Problem was that I did connect with tenant "SYSTEMDB" instead of "System database container":

[image]

Which results in almost the same connection - but with less privileges!!